# What can make a program not capable to take advantages of 64 bit system?

Tags: 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, v8, 32-bit, embedded-v8

I am looking into Google V8 Javascript Engine. It is said that they are having problems for porting to 64 bit systems.

What kind of programming or programming constraints can make a program a 32-bit or 64-bit specific, apart from building and testing them on 64 bit machine with 64 bit settings ?

Comment: it would be a better learning for me if you could tell me why the downvote ?

Answer (score 0):

You may check this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing) which says:-

> The main disadvantage of 64-bit architectures is that, relative to
>   32-bit architectures, the same data occupies more space in memory (due
>   to longer pointers and possibly other types, and alignment padding).
>   This increases the memory requirements of a given process and can have
>   implications for efficient processor cache utilization. Maintaining a
>   partial 32-bit model is one way to handle this, and is in general
>   reasonably effective. For example, the z/OS operating system takes
>   this approach, requiring program code to reside in 31-bit address
>   spaces (the high order bit is not used in address calculation on the
>   underlying hardware platform) while data objects can optionally reside
>   in 64-bit regions.

Comment: My question is not about which is better, but why some softwares find it difficult to port to 64 bit when they want to port it ?